# Aws lex repeat intent multiple times

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-lex

I m trying to repeat an intent in aws lex multiple times, 3rd time hang up phrase populates. I have a confirmation prompt which ask whether they want to add more products. If yes I want that intent to be repeated as many times the user wishes to add.

Comment: Can you share what you have written so far?

Comment: if (event.currentIntent.confirmationStatus === 'Confirmed') {
    return  {
     "dialogAction": {
       "type": "ElicitSlot",
        "intentName": "NewRequirement",
         "slots": {
             "product": null,
             "quantity": null,
             "uoms": null
           },
          "slotToElicit" : "product",
       }
      }
    } The above code is written in initiatilization and validation lambda function so that when it is confirmed ask for products and continue asking for quantity. Later i changed to elicitIntent which is working. But above code is not working.

Comment: Elicit Intent would break out of your loop. I imagine that this is what you want to do after having added the products to a basket of sorts and then called your backend service for fulfillment. What errors are you seeing?